# problema ao conectar no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\lojavirtual\conecta.php on line 3 Não foi possivel conectar

Answer (score 0):

Você deve estar misturando `mysqli` com `mysql` ou informando parâmetro errado.

Use assim:

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect("host","usuario","senha") or die ("Erro ao conectar ao banco"); 

mysqli_select_db($conexao, "nome_do_banco") or die ("Banco não encontrado");
```